# Error when using write() printing stat structure

Tags: c

I am trying to use `write()` to print out st->st_size

When I do the line

```
write(fd, st->st_size, sizeof(st->st_size));
```

I get the error below.

```
   `warning: passing argument 2 of ‘write’ makes pointer from integer without 
    a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       write(fd, st->st_size, sizeof(st->st_size));`

 `In file included from myls.c:4:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:369:16: note: expected ‘const void *’ but argument is of type ‘__off_t {aka long int}’
 extern ssize_t write (int __fd, const void *__buf, size_t __n) __wur;`
```

Is there any way that I could fix this? It does it for all other simliar members in the `stat` structure

Comment: It's telling you exactly what's wrong: the st_size field is an integer type (specifically an off_t). Write requires a pointer to the bytes to write. If you want to write the integer value as binary, use `&(st->st_size)`.

Comment: If you want to print out the value (which usually means print a textual representation) then you won't get success with `write()`, which just outputs the binary data from memory addressed by its second parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the second parameter, `st->st_size`.  That's an integer or long value. Now look at the declaration of `write`:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

`write` expects an address of a variable as the second parameter, and the third parameter is how many bytes to copy from that address into the file descriptor.

This is likely what you want:

```
write(fd, &(st->st_size), sizeof(st->st_size));
```

The above will write out the **binary** representation of `st_size` to the file descriptor. If you want to write that value out ***as text***, you should probably consider different ways to do that. Including:

```
const size_t tmpbufsize = 50;
char tmp[tmpbufsize]; // big enough to hold a 64-bit int
snprint(tmp, tmpbufsize, "%ll", (long long)(st->st_size));
write(fd, tmp, strlen(tmp));
```

Comment: [Per POSIX, `st_size` is of type `off_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html).  Also [per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html):  "blkcnt_t and off_t shall be signed integer types."  I have no idea how a size can be negative, but ....

Comment: @AndrewHenle - thanks for calling that out. I was lazily looking up the typedef of `off_t`, since I'm not on my window box. But I didn't get very far.  I'll fix shortly.

Comment: `sprint(tmp, "%ll", (long long)(st->st_size));` -> `snprintf(tmp, sizeof tmp, "%lld", (long long)st->st_size);`

Comment: @selbie: not completely fixed: `snprint` -> `snprintf` and `%ll` -> `%lld`